# Running DIGITS in CPU mode only

Tags: gpu, nvidia, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

[image]

I am trying to build a model in DIGITS. I am using CPU only to do the learning.. However, I get a CUDA driver version error although I am not using GPU. What could this problem be? I have attached my solver.prototxt below. [image]

Comment: have you tried to build caffe in CPU_ONLY mode?

Comment: Yes! I did.. and it got resolved..

Comment: dI have the exact same problem but I already compiled caffe in `CPU_ONLY` mode. why is it happening? I have just downloaded the `MNIST` dataset and trying to create a model hence the error shown in this question